# SQL SERVER 2012 high availability and cluster for deploy share point 2013 Internet portal

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server-2012, disaster-recovery

We have plan to deploy a huge SharePoint 2013 internet portal and we are using sql server back end.

The daily have 500 to 1000 concurrent users and for sql server cluster and  high availability and disaster recovery what recommendation we will implement and how to implement these scenarios for where to start?

Answer (score 2):

AlwaysOn is a great new feature to SQL Server 2012 that allows consuming clients to have a mirroring and failover database solution all transparently for a single named instance. SharePoint is one such consumer of SQL and depends on having a solid connectivity to run. If SQL goes down, so does SharePoint so it’s well within our interests to configure a bullet-proof SQL Server solution that just won’t die.

[SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server AlwaysOn - High Availability SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2013/04/24/sharepoint-2013-and-sql-server-alwayson-high-availability-sharepoint.aspx)

for high availability portal, you have to make sure, you implement Loadbalanced WFE, also redundant App servers.

Check the traditional and streamline typologies from this articles for more info.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx